# regex for function call that takes 0 or more integers

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I am looking for some regex help to parse function name and its parameters.

`f()` is valid and has no parameters - should return `[<f,[]>]` (array of map of function name and array of parameters).

`f(); g()` are two functions f and g with no parameters - should return `[<f,[], <g,[]>]`

`f(1,2)` - function f with two parameters - should return `[<f, [1,2]>]`

`f(1,2);    g(1)`  should return `[<f, [1,2]>; <g, [1]>]`

So basically its a semicolon delimited series of functionName(one or more comma delimited parameters of integer / number type only).

I am looking for a regex with matchers approach to get this to work.

Comment: sorry didn't realize that got posted. there were formatting questions in there. Don't understand the barage of -1's though

Comment: So to be clear, you explicitly ignore things like `f(g(1))`, `f("1, 1")`, `f((1, 1))`, `f(..args)` and so on?

Comment: @Andreas i realize that you are moderator and have high stackoverflow but please don't jump to conclusions. If you think the above can be solved without resorting to some kind of custom lexer or parser, I would love to engage in that debate.

Comment: In what way did I suggest anything of the sort? You are asking us to write a regex, without even attempting to do so yourself, i.e. it reads as a write-the-code-for-me question, and that is not what this site is about. Did you even follow the link to see the explanation of why?

Comment: okay feel good man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some regex with patterns like this :

```
List<String> functions = Arrays.asList("f()", "f(); g()", "f(1,2)", "f(1,2);    g(1)");
String regex = "([a-z]+\\(.*?\\));?";
String regex2 = "([a-z]+)\\((.*?)\\)";
for (String func : functions) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(func);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(regex2);
        Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(matcher.group(1));
        if (matcher2.find()) {
            System.out.println("function name = " + matcher2.group(1) + ", params "
                    + Arrays.asList(matcher2.group(2).split(",")));
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Output**

```
function name = f, params []
function name = f, params []
function name = g, params []
function name = f, params [1, 2]
function name = f, params [1, 2]
function name = g, params [1]
```

---

**Details :**

- The first regex `([a-z]+\(.*?\));?` to get extract functions, because it can be more than one function than you need to loop to get one by one ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ziXMyW/1))
- The second regex `([a-z]+)\((.*?)\)` to get the name of function and every thing between parenthesis ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ziXMyW/2))
- So when you get every thing between parenthesis you can split with `,` to get the list of parameters

Comment: thanks this is really nice. One issue thought is that the parameters inside the functions are number type only. I could do an Integer.parseInt() to eliminate strings but is there a more elegant way.

Comment: you can complete and use a regex so you can check `if(param.matches("\\d+")){` to eliminate strings  ;)

Comment: thanks :) .. i had contemplated if I should use some sort of lexer & parser logic to make the solution more robust. This should work unless the requirements changes drastically.